# dotMemory memory profiling

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide

So I run 100 http requests to my webApi with Apache jMeter, and I got dotMemory snapshot below:
[image]
[image]

How exactly am I suppose to find the memory leak from this?

Comment: It tells you, for instance, right below "Event handlers leak" what the reason for the leak is. What's confusing?

Comment: how to apply this finding to my code?

Answer (score 2):

Look where these instances of RuntimeType were created and you will find the root of a leak. I guess it is the XmlSerializer which creates a dynamic assembly on each instance of XmlSerializer.